# Romans 4:5 earliest evidence (P40 Baden Papyrus 57)

Tags: romans

Does anyone know where I can get a picture of P40 ( Baden Papyrus 57), specifically the part with Romans 4:5?

I have contacted Heidelberg, Institut fur Papyrologie der Univ., (Inv. 645) but no answer yet.

Comment: Is there a special motivation for this request?

Comment: Yes, I wanted to show some Mormon friends how, *if* I trust the validity of a Bible passage translation, based on what I can see in the earliest copies (such as the existence or absence of a word) as a stronger evidence than what their prophet Joseph Smith claimed as being erred/corrected (without any textual critical or archaeological evidence), how would they explain believing in their prophet's version of a passage that totally contradicts evidence (in the case of Romans 4:5, the absence of the equivalent to the English "not" conditioning 'justifying the unjust'. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps it is [this](http://ntvmr.uni-muenster.de/manuscript-workspace?docid=10040&biblicalContent=Rom.4&searchType=pages) that you are looking for?